# Trying to add text from a random line from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, random, pygame, readlines

I am making a game in pygame for my sister for practising in pygame and I am trying to add a random line from a text file in to window name:

import pygame,random,sys

```
RandomMess = open('GameText.txt')
pygame.display.set_caption('Dream Land: {}').
#The .txt file currently has 4 lines but will be a lot more in the future... 
#These are the test lines: This is in beta, hi :), hello, hi
```

I have all the rest of the code in case anyone says that I haven't done any other code to make the window or anything.
I want it to say: Dream Land: {} then in the braces add a random line from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for readlines() and random.choice().

```
import random,sys

RandomMess = open('GameText.txt')

# .readlines() will create a list of the lines in the file.
# So in our case ['This is in beta', 'hi :)', 'hello', 'hi']
# random.choice() then picks one item from this list.
line = random.choice(RandomMess.readlines())

# Then use .format() to add the line into the caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Dream Land: {}'.format(line))
```